# New React Native Project gives error on running the bundle install

Tags: react-native, rubygems, bundler

I have created a new React Native project based on Typescript, and while running the bundle install command, I am getting the following error

```
An error occurred while installing ffi
(1.16.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I have tried almost all the available solutions referenced on the internet, but none of them are working. Does anyone have any latest solution for this?

Comment: check this https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/937